# .NET DataSet equivalent in python

Tags: c#, python, dataset

I'm wondering if there is a dataSet object library in python like in c# dataSet objects.
Any good links of tutorials and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Entirely depends on which database binding you use.

Comment: @delnan ? You probably mean "which Object Relacional Mapper" library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQLAlchemy's Object Relational Mapper.

[SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [IronPython](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/) implementation of python, then you can use exactly the same DataSet object that is used in C#.